# How can I connect with square production environment?

Tags: square

​My client is already using square as his payment system. I created a developer account by myself and I was able to process orders using sandbox environment. Now I would like to send orders to production environment for the existing account of my client.

I would like to know what is the process to accomplish that.

1.Does my client need to set a developer account by himself and share me his Application ID, Access token and location id?

2.if I finish the process to validate my developer account to process payments, will I be able to connect with the location id from my client?

3.Does he need to add my as a Team member in order to see his location in my account?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing a custom application for one client that uses Square or are you going to have many clients that use Square use your application? If you’re developing a solution for one client you can ask them to create an application and configure their credentials to make the API calls. Otherwise you’ll want to use OAuth that will allow many sellers use your integration.